# How to save API Host URL to local storage and retrieve it on start

Tags: angular

How to save the API URL to local Storage and then retrieve it on the Application Load.

Normal reading and saving to local storage is a piece of cake.

How the whole setup is:

1. Preference service which should save or retrieve from the local storage.
2. API service where all the api calls are made.
3. Settings component with a input field to set the API Host URL.

when the user goes to the Settings page and enters the URL, it will get saved into the localstorage. That data should be fetched by the Preference service and then API service should get the data and call that specified URL endpoint.

The problem is that when i try this flow, the api service is not able to get the URL from the localstorage, hence the api call fails.

How should this be implemented properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `localStorage` to store EndPoint in `localStorage`, on Loading `app.module.ts or app.component.ts constructor` set a Global/Exported variable value then use it while making http calls.

Comment: why not, feel free to talk.